# Quickly + GtkWindow default close button

Tags: window, gtk, pygtk, tray

I made a gtk app with Ubuntu quickly tool.But I have encountered a few problems with the window close button(the one in the top left of the window).So here's the thing: I want my app to close in the system tray ,so I write the code in a method ,create a button on my window and connect the "clicked" signal to my method.Everything is working as it should.Now I want my window close button to do the same thing.When i look up on the code written by quickly i found this method:

```
 def on_destroy(self, widget, data=None):
    # Clean up code for saving application state should be added here.
    Gtk.main_quit()
```

So instead of Gtk.main_quit() I called my handler for the button I deployed on my window.The thing now is that my app is hiding on the system tray but when i want to unhide it there is no window,although I can see the process of my app is alive.
I want to say that when I use the button i created I can see my app when I unhide it ,so it's quite obvious that when I press the system close button there's more than one signal.

So my question is what other signals are called when I close my window from system button?And where is the place quickly implements the handler for the other signals?

Thank for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your window is `"destroy"`. Connecting to that signal allows you to run some code, but, your window is still destroyed. If you're aren't breaking out of the main loop with `Gtk.main_quit()` then your app is still running. To re-display the window you would need to recreate it.

Another option is to instead connect a callback function to the `"delete-event"` of the window. In this signal handler if you return `True` then the window will *not* be destroyed. In other words, you could hide the window and return `True` and then re-show the window later. If you return `False` from this signal handler then the window will continue to be destroyed.

Comment: You are the man! Thank for your help!I should've read more carefully the gtk api.  Thank you again!